# Separable differential equation ('show that' question)

Tags: integration

I have been asked to show that if $$dN = -\lambda Ndt+Pdt$$ then

$$N(t) = \frac{P(1-e^{-\lambda t})}{\lambda}$$

So this is separable, and can be rearranged to read

$$\frac{1}{P-\lambda N} dN = dt$$ which integrates to give

$$\frac{-1}{\lambda}ln(P-\lambda N) = t+C$$ where C is an arbitrary constant. Rearranging and raising both sides to the power of e doesn't give the required result, so have I integrated wrong? That was my first thought, but wolfram alpha seems to agree with my integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{-1}{\lambda}ln(P-\lambda N) = t+C\\
ln(P-\lambda N) = -\lambda t+C\\
P-\lambda N = Ce^{-\lambda t}\\
N = \dfrac{Ce^{-\lambda t}-P}{-\lambda}\\
N = \dfrac{P(1-Ce^{-\lambda t})}{\lambda}$

Set C = 1 for a particular solution, let it be C for a more general solution.  Or, if you were given initial conditions, that will determine C for you.

Comment: There isn't a P in front of the exp term to factorise out though!

Comment: Do we just adjust the constant so it can be there?

Comment: The P in front of the exp term... C is arbitrary  $C/P = C$.  There will always be an arbitrary constant.  Really this problem should say that N(t) as given above is a solution to the diff eq.  It is not the only solution.